# Avoid chest exercises for flat chest

Tags: exercise, workout-routines, chest

My goal is to have flat chest. Something in line with what Paul Walker has in [this picture](http://www.2flashgames.com/photo/paul_walker/Paul_Walker_0006.htm).

From my general observation, I have found that surfers & swimmers have that kind of physique specially flat chest.  Unfortunately it's not possible for me to become either. I swim once per week (Sunday) and workout 5 days per week (excluding swimming).

It would be great to know if I am on right track. Or Am I doing something wrong? Or should I be doing something different?

Here's the summary of what I am doing to achieve my goal.

I am 5"11 and weigh 162 lbs. I neither want to gain weight nor lose any.

1. Diet - eating vegetarian salads & stir fry (Olive oil) vegetables 4 days per week (no dressings, no cheese but I do add tofu). For 2 days of the week I eat normal protein and carbs rich food.  I make Sundays a cheat day and eat anything I want but in limited quantity.
2. I avoid doing bench press, push-ups and if I do then I do with very light weights because I have seen that my chest is usually pumped after doing above exercises.
3. Concentrate on Biceps, Shoulder, abs and legs.
4. Whey Protein isolate shake (30 grams of protein) every day.
5. I started above routine in November 2010 have lost around 2.35 inches from my belly but have not notices much difference in my chest.

Comment: I'd recommend against avoiding muscle groups, because this creates an imbalance. Rather use workouts focused on endurance rather than strength.

Comment: Can you elaborate _why_ you want a flat chest? Hearing your motivations and reasons might give people better ideas on _how_ you should achieve what you want.

Comment: Your muscles also look "pumped" after working out because that's what happens when you work out any muscle. I don't know what happens biologically, but it's not permanent either. Building muscle and stressing them are different things.

Comment: Muscle "pump" is a result of increased blood flow to the region being exercised and goes away after the exercise is over.

Comment: Maybe you have narrow shoulders, wider hips, giving the illusion of a peaky chest? A slumpy posture can also, as can internally rotated shoulders.

Comment: It does not take a lot o body fat around the pec muscles to really change their appearance.  Unfortunately for everyone, there is no site-specific fat burning routine.  If this affects you, you might consider cutting out some cheat days. Have you ever defined your body shape? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ectomorphic

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, if you don't want to build muscles, then don't use them. Hope you don't ever have to use them though. If you aren't working them, they also won't get stronger. I'm rather curious as to why you would not want to build muscle on your chest, but what you're doing sounds like it should work to that goal just fine.

Comment: In addition to md5sum's answer, you are seeing loss from your stomach first because that's a primary area for fat storage. As you continue to lose weight, you will eventually lose it from your chest as well if you have excess fat there.

Comment: I wouldn't say swimmers don't use them, they just use them in a more allround way then weightlifters ;-)

Comment: Swimmers use their pecs very little and with very little resistance. They have a ton of super-low resistance repetition though.

Comment: Not using your muscles causes them to shrink which also causes your appear to be more "flabby" once you stop. I've heard that's why people believe "muscle turns into fat" which doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

To get a flat chest carry out the various push ups.  For example doing press ups with the hands on the floor as wide as possible works differently to hands close together. Second lots of skipping, sometimes hard to get into but practice and I promise it does get easier.  Finally running long and short distances.  Finally once a flat chest is being achieved over the next 12 months, do weights with just a small resistance and repeat high volume.  Take up martial arts training and do lots of stretching. After all this your metabolism will change and you will never have man boobs again.